# What is the difference between these two codes regarding interface?

Tags: java

I am currently learning java. I just don't understand the use of interface and I am really confused about it.

These two codes return the same answer, then what is the use of interface here?

```
interface Jumpable {
abstract int maxDistance();
}
class Animal implements Jumpable {
public int maxDistance() {
return 100;
}
}
public class Forest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Animal lion = new Animal();
System.out.println(lion.maxDistance());
}
}
```

```
class Animal {
public int maxDistance() {
return 100;
}
}
public class Forest {
public static void main(String args[]) {
Animal lion = new Animal();
System.out.println(lion.maxDistance());
}
}
```

Comment: When asking other people for help, it's well worth taking a moment to ensure your code is property indented and formatted. (It's well worth doing when *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: The interface lets you declare *other implementations*, e.g. for testing purposes. It also allows you to write functionality that relies on the *interface*, rather than any one concrete implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the state your code is in right now, there is no difference, but that is not what it is about. Further down the line you will need to do things with your animals, without knowing what animals you have or what they can do.
Suppose you want to subclass your animals, into mammals, birds and insects. Some of them can jump, but not others. It will be very ugly code if you create specific classes or attributes for mammals that can jump etc. If you instead create an interface, you have lots of options. You can create a list of animals that can jump, and then tell them to jump, regardless of their type. 
Later, you might want to add screaming to your animals. Just add an interface for that.